solve a question in geometric sequence
In a geometric sequence with n terms, the sum of terms without the last one is 480, the sum of the terms without the first is 1440, and the 3rd term is larger by 72 from the 2nd term. what is n?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
